# How to change instance method's visibility

Tags: ruby, visibility

I want to change an instance method's visibility from public to private.

```
ooo = Object.new
def ooo.some_public; 'woot' end
ooo.some_public # => "woot"
ooo.respond_to?(:some_public) # => true
```

I want `ooo.some_public` to be private. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ooo = Object.new
def ooo.some_public; 'woot' end
ooo.respond_to?(:some_public) # => true
ooo.singleton_class.class_eval{private :some_public}
ooo.respond_to?(:some_public) # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is defining private singleton method. It can be done this way:

```
class << ooo
  private
  def some_public
    'woot'
  end
end
ooo.respond_to?(:some_public)
# => false
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the existing method visibility in runtime you may use call to `Kernel#private` method:

```
private :some_public
```

Or, more precisely:

```
class << ooo
  private :some_public  
end  
# ⇒ <Class:#<Object:0x00000003467140>> < Object
ooo.respond_to?(:some_public)
# ⇒ false
```

Hope it helps.